# Doctrine 2 persist failing to insert due to missing ID

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

While trying to do an insert using with Doctrine 2's persist-flush method, I've been unable to get this to work at all. The metadata is set to generate a value (I've tried AUTO and IDENTITY with no success), but it's still not auto-incrementing. I've also noticed on the database's schema, the "id" column is not set to auto-increment either. The entity in question contains no pre/post-persist functions.

> Entity of type XXXX is missing an assigned ID for field 'id'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

```
/**
 * @Id 
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @GeneratedValue
 */
protected $id;
```

I was wondering if anyone had any insight on this, as I can't seem to find any google or stackoverflow results that helped. Thanks!

Comment: When you set `@GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` did you clear annotation cache and tried to update the schema?

Comment: I cleared all three caches (query, metadata, and result) with the flush switch with no change.

Comment: If you are using doctrine ORM then your annotation is wrong. you need to declare it like '@ORM\Id',  '@ORM\Column(type="integer")', '@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")'

Comment: I have "use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;" at the beginning of my file, so it should work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it appears the problem was due to having more than one column with a @GeneratedValue annotation (Even if it's set to NONE). Removing those and leaving the $id with the only one fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prefix your annotations with `@ORM\`, like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

...

/**
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
protected $id;
```

Comment: Attempted that, getting this now:
`[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "XXXX" sub class of "YYYY". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.` Seems like it's ignoring the annotations now (Tried clear-flushing the caches again for kicks).

Comment: Is that related to this entity? Can you paste the source code of the whole entity in your question?

Comment: I see, the same applies, of course, to all of your Doctrine annotations - `@Entity` to `@ORM\Entity`, `@Table` to `@ORM\Table` and so on ...

Comment: Getting this now: `[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Class "Entity\WatchNotify" sub class of "XY\Doctrine\Entity" is not a valid
 entity or mapped super class.` I suspect due to the fact that it doesn't regard the entity anymore as an entity because of the @ORM\ prefixes causing the annotation not to work. Removing the @ORM\ off of Table and Entity does fix this and returns me to the previous error, so I suspect it's nothing to do with the @ORM\ being missing.

Comment: I have noticed that by removing the @Id, it complains about the entity requiring an identifier/primary key. So I think the syntax is correct, Just need to figure out why it's not auto-generating the number before the persist.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by doing a cache clear.